# How to reuse variables in Mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, mocha.js

In my mocha tests I always require the same libs. For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  User = mongoose.model('User'),
  _ = require('underscore');
```

I want to use them in every test file like this:

```
describe('xxx', function () {
  it('xxx', function (done) {
    var user = new User();
    done();
  });
});
```

without using any prefix like `var user = new somefile.User();`
How to do this or are there any better solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is not possible.

Mocha has a `-r` (or `--require` in the long version) parameter which helps you to require modules, but as the [documentation](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) states:

> The `--require` option is useful for libraries such as should.js, so you may simply `--require should` instead of manually invoking `require('should')` within each test file. Note that this works well for should as it augments `Object.prototype`, however if you wish to access a module's exports you will have to require them, for example `var should = require('should')`.

What I could imagine as a workaround is to introduce a helper file which basically does nothing but export all the required modules you need using a single module (which basically comes to down to what you suggested with a `prefix`):

```
module.exports = {
  mongoose: require('mongoose'),
  User: mongoose.model('User'),
  _: require('underscore')
};
```

This allows you to only import *one* module in your actual test files (the helper file), and access all the other modules as sub-objects, such as:

```
var helper = require('./helper');

describe('xxx', function () {
  it('xxx', function (done) {
    var user = new helper.User();
    done();
  });
});
```

Probably there is a better name than `helper` that you can use, but basically this could be a way to make it work.

Comment: Yes I see. What I want is very similar to `private static` field in Java. But it's not how it work in js.